# Issue with reformatting a date using sed

Tags: bash, sed

I'm working on a shell script to reformat a CSV file exported from Access into a format that can be imported more easily into MySQL.

There's a number of different operations I need to perform on the file, and I'm currently stuck on one of them. I've used sed and awk a bit before, but I'm not great with them (I'm used to PCRE), and I'm at a loss to figure out where I've gone wrong here.

The command I've written is as follows:

```
sed -e '1d' raw.csv | sed 's/£//g' | sed 's/ 00:00:00//g' | sed 's/\([0-9]{2}\)\/\([0-9]{2}\)\/\([0-9]{2}\)/20\3-\1-\2/g' > formatted.csv
```

Now, the operations I carry out here are as follows:

- Delete the first line
- Remove all pound signs
- Remove all unwanted instances of `00:00:00`
- Reformat the date from mm/dd/yy to yyyy-mm-dd

I've worked my way through these in order and they work as expected, except for the last one:

```
sed 's/\([0-9]{2}\)\/\([0-9]{2}\)\/\([0-9]{2}\)/20\3-\1-\2/g' > formatted.csv
```

Can anyone see where I've gone astray?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to escape the curly brackets too.

```
sed 's/\([0-9]\{2\}\)\/\([0-9]\{2\}\)\/\([0-9]\{2\}\)/20\3-\1-\2/g' > formatted.csv
```